# Where are the exposed headers informing my Rate Limit for the Geni API?

Tags: xmlhttprequest, http-headers, rate-limiting, response-headers

Anytime I use the [Client Side Flow](https://www.geni.com/platform/developer/help/oauth_client_side?version=1) to authorize my [Geni](https://www.geni.com/platform/developer/help) app with OAuth2, I can successfully get it to authenticate me but I receive the error:

`{"error":{"type":"ApiException","message":"Rate limit exceeded."}}`

(I am using the endpoint [`https://www.geni.com/api/user/metadata?ids="[my_id]"`](https://www.geni.com/platform/developer/help/api?path=user%2Fmetadata&version=1))

According to the [documentation](https://www.geni.com/platform/developer/help/rate_limits?version=1), the rate limits can be checked within the HTTP headers.
[image: Geni's Rate Limits documentation]
However, when I check the Response Headers within Google Chrome's Network tab, all I see is:

```
==Response Headers==
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description, X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, X-API-Rate-Limit, X-API-Rate-Remaining, X-API-Rate-Window

Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS

Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description, X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version, X-API-Rate-Limit, X-API-Rate-Remaining, X-API-Rate-Window
```

---

So things like `X-API-Rate-Window` are THERE, [given permission to be exposed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers), but they're only *values* instead of the *keys* and there are no corresponding additional headers with those names used as the keys. Therefore, I can't figure out a way to extract any useful information from them.

Can someone advise me on how to read what my remaining Rate Limit is, and how I can access metadata information without tripping it?

Thanks!

(P.S. I've posted this question to [Geni's forums](https://www.geni.com/platform/developer/forum/topic?last_page=true&topic_id=211) and have received no response which is why I am posting it here :) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this. I learned about [preflight requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) and how that was the request whose Response Headers I was looking at before.

It turns out Geni *was* passing its custom headers to my main request, I just had a line of code in my own proxy PHP file that was omitting most headers.

```php
  foreach ( $header_text as $header ) {
    if ( preg_match( '/^(?:Content-Type|Content-Language|Set-Cookie):/i', $header ) ) {
      header( $header );
    }
  }
```

(I was using [this proxy](https://github.com/cowboy/php-simple-proxy/), for reference.)

When I removed that regex check from the proxy, all of the headers began appearing!